# How do I manage inter-branch dependencies in Perforce?

Tags: maven, build, branch, version, perforce

We are using Perforce and Maven and we are in a situation where we have one branch A that hosts a mature project and another branch B, that we are starting to dev on that uses the code hosted in the first branch.

I anticipate that going forward, there could be cases where a check-in into Branch A will result in failed compilation in Branch B because the developers working on them are not aware of specific usages and cross-dependencies. And then devs will waste time updating B code and figure that its not compiling.

Branch/project A needs to remain as its own separate entity because it's code could be used in another future project.

Can someone advice me around handling and alleviating such problem? Any best-practices that you guys can suggest? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a build environment:

1) Set up a continuous integration (CI) server, such as Jenkins.  When a developer commits to Branch A, it should detect the commit and trigger a build.

2) When Branch A completes its build, it deploys its artifacts to a shared repository. Highly recommended (buy not strictly necessary) is that the build for Branch A deploys to a Repository Server, such as Nexus (but a repository in [source control](http://code.google.com/p/maven-svn-wagon/wiki/MavenRepositoryInsideGoogleCode) or a [FTP server does the job too](http://stuartsierra.com/2009/09/08/run-your-own-maven-repository)).

3) Set up Branch B in your CI server, but with a build "trigger" that runs whenever a build for Branch A succeeds.

4) Configure both build configurations to email relevant team members (or everybody?) whenever a build fails.

Also, both branches should depend on your repository from #2 above.  If you need the entire environment to be repeatable and self-contained, go the repository-in-scm route.